# Как установить в ubuntu на Anacondy библиотеку keras?

Tags: ubuntu, keras, anaconda

Как установить в ubuntu на Anacondy библиотеку keras ??

[*вопрос является переводом с английского вопроса.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747742/install-keras-in-anaconda3-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

у меня установилась так .

```
(base) dima@komp:~$ source activate target_env
Could not find conda environment: target_env
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

(base) dima@komp:~$ pip install keras
Collecting keras
  Downloading Keras-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from keras) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from keras) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from keras) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from keras) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from h5py->keras) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: keras
Successfully installed keras-2.4.3
(base) dima@komp:~$
```

---

Пишет vell001:

во-первых, вам нужно переключить `conda_env` на  `target_environment`

```
source activate target_env
```

во-вторых, используйте `pip` для установки  `keras`

```
pip install keras
```

---

Пишет Harvett:

Простейший метод  `conda install keras` это сработало у меня.

Comment: Если уж вы пишите подсказку для человека, который собирается заниматься задачами ML, но при этом не понимает, как устанавливать пакеты через `conda/pip`, и будет искать ответ в поисковике, а не в документации к пакету, то зачем заведомо вводить в заблуждение с виртуальным окружением (которое вовсе не обязательно, и которое надо сначала создать, а потом уже активировать)? И вообще, в итоге `pip` или `conda`?

Comment: @mkkik здравствуйте , если вас не устраивает мой ответ вы можете дать свой . С уважением тимоб256

Comment: Да меня вопрос не устраивает больше чем ответ.